# Selenium con python, Seleccionar una opción google form

Tags: python, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome

Estoy probando y experimentando un poco con Selenium, quiero automatizar el rellenado de un formulario de google form, teniendo ya las respuestas desde un excel. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time

def rellenar_formulario(driver, etiqueta, valor):
    try:
        if etiqueta in etiquetas_select:
            # Localiza y haz clic en el elemento 'select'
            select_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//span[text()='{etiqueta}']/following::div[3]")))
            select_element.click()
            
           # Espera explícita para asegurarse de que el elemento sea interactuable
            option_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='vRMGwf']/span[text()='{valor}']")))
            
            
            # Desplazarse hasta el elemento
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option_element)
            
            # Hacer clic en el elemento
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", option_element)
        else:
            # Localiza y llena el campo de texto
            campo = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//span[text()='{etiqueta}']/following::input[1]")))
            campo.send_keys(str(valor))
            
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(f"No se encontró el elemento con la etiqueta {etiqueta}")
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"Se agotó el tiempo de espera para la etiqueta {etiqueta}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error inesperado con la etiqueta {etiqueta}: {e}")

# (El resto del código se mantiene igual)


# Ruta al archivo Excel con las respuestas
archivo_excel = 'datos.xlsx'

# ... (Imports and function definition remain the same)

# Initialize the browser driver (in this example, Chrome)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the Google form
form_url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfwmmrhJAsJvnqa-bOLiCd-WI_Tu8-rhm99ouFyy662HNUtGQ/viewform'
driver.get(form_url)

# Load the Excel file
workbook = load_workbook(filename=archivo_excel)
sheet = workbook.active

# Form labels and labels that are 'select' elements
form_labels = ['FUNCIONARIO', 'SECRETARIA', 'REPORTES', 'SOPORTE', 'RESPONSABLES', 'ESTADO']
etiquetas_select = ['SECRETARIA', 'REPORTES', 'RESPONSABLES', 'ESTADO']

# Iterate through the rows in the Excel file
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    for label, value in zip(form_labels, row):
        time.sleep(4)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//span[text()='{label}']")))
        rellenar_formulario(driver, label, value)

    # Submit the form
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Enviar']")))
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Enviar']").click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Could not find the submit button: {e}")

    # Pause before moving on to the next row
    time.sleep(6)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Dejo el link del formulario por si desean ver el html para guiarse --> https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfwmmrhJAsJvnqa-bOLiCd-WI_Tu8-rhm99ouFyy662HNUtGQ/viewform. La cuestion es que los formularios que tienen select me lo abre, pero no me escoge la opción que necesito. La verdad agradecería mucho la ayuda.

La opción que necesito resaltar es esta

```
# Espera explícita para asegurarse de que el elemento sea interactuable

            option_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='vRMGwf']/span[text()='{valor}']")))
            
            
            # Desplazarse hasta el elemento
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", option_element)
            
            # Hacer clic en el elemento
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", option_element)
```

Y el error que sale es el siguiente:

Comment: No me dejaba publicar con el error

Comment: Que aviso te daba al intentar poner el error?

Comment: Que mucho código y no me dejaba seguir para la publicación

Comment: Puedes poner el error en un pastebin o algo así lo agregamos por ti?

Comment: Te agradecería bastante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Para automatizar el* **formulario de Google**, *recomiendo realizar una solicitud* **HTTP** **POST** *utilizando la biblioteca* [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) *de Python, ya que es más eficiente y simple que el código de Selenium. Esto permite enviar datos a un servidor sin necesidad de una interfaz de navegador.*

En lo que respecta a los formularios de Google, existe un patrón de entrada que puede ser manipulado mediante una solicitud POST. Cada entrada, ya sea a través de un `input` de `select` o un `radio button`, está marcada con una secuencia única de números que teóricamente representa el campo. Se representa mediante una clave y un valor.

Al analizar el código fuente de la página de formularios de Google y buscar `entry`, te encontrarás con estos inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="entry.386121518" value="">
```

Cada uno de estos valores que se encuentran después de `entry.` tiene una secuencia numérica que representa cada campo del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**(** *Observa que cada campo tiene la entrada (entry) con el número que corresponde a la respuesta correcta; colocar una respuesta de un campo que no tiene la respuesta correspondiente causará un error al enviar el formulario* **)**

Una vez que identifiques cada uno y lo que representa, puedes enviar una solicitud *POST* con los valores correspondientes, de esta manera, podrás enviar el formulario completo con toda la información.

Codigo

```
import requests

url1 = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfwmmrhJAsJvnqa-bOLiCd-WI_Tu8-rhm99ouFyy662HNUtGQ/viewform'
url2 = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfwmmrhJAsJvnqa-bOLiCd-WI_Tu8-rhm99ouFyy662HNUtGQ/formResponse'


respuestas= {

"entry.386121518"  : "ROBINSON",
"entry.768225071"  : "SALUD",
"entry.616928787"  : "FIREWALL",
"entry.1989502650" : "SOPORTE",
"entry.1918917695" : "ROBINSON VILLABON GUZMAN",
"entry.373219081"  : "ABIERTO",
"entry.487915391"  : "ESTO ES UNA PRUEBA"}


s = requests.Session()
s.get(url1)
resp = s.post(url2, data=respuestas)
print(resp) # <Response [200]>
```

La `url1` representa el formulario y la `url2` la respuesta.

`s = requests.Session()` es para mantener el control del estado de la conexión, de esta forma no es necesario especificar la información para cada solicitud.

`s.get(url1)` recupera la visualización de la página.

Como el formulario tiene campos obligatorios, no tendrá éxito si se dejan campos vacíos, debe especificar la entrada y el valor numérico correspondiente, y la respuesta de esta manera el resultado será 200 y las respuestas serán confirmadas por los formularios.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista y perdón mi ignorancia, pero ejecuto una prueba y me manda el 400, supongo que el input de los select espera un valor que ellos colocan y no el nombre como tal que uno envia, entonces siempre me enviá el error 400 cuando intento de enviar la solicitud con todos los campos

Comment: La causa podría ser que alguna información de Excel no siguió el orden del campo. Es posible que haya ingresado el valor en un campo donde no haya una opción.
Sería de gran ayuda si pudiera proporcionar una parte de Excel para ver cómo el bucle está presentando los datos

Comment: No le integré excel, lo hice con datos quemados
respuestas = {
    "entry.386121518": "ROBINSON",
    "entry.1989502650": "SALUD",
    "entry.487915391": "FIREWALL",
    "entry.768225071": "SOPORTE",
    "entry.616928787": "ROBINSON VILLABON GUZMAN",
    "entry.1918917695": "ABIERTO",
    "entry.373219081": "ESTO ES UNA PRUEBA",
}

Comment: El error 400 ocurrió porque asoció el "entry" con el campo que no corresponde con la respuesta

Comment: Eres mi idolo, ya entendí todo, muchas gracias, perdón por los poquitos puntos